# How to access an ASP Control in a class file

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp Textbox control in my .aspx page. I have a .cs class file , not the code behind file. I want to access this textbox control in this .cs file. I know I can pass it as a parameter.But I'm curious to know if I can do it through some reference way or something.

Comment: No - there is no other way. To get a control, you need a reference to the Page. You don't have to necessarily pass the control, but at the very least you need to pass a reference to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another scenario.

**If** you have a .cs page like `BasePage.cs` that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`, and **if** your code-behind class inherits from this BasePage, then in the BasePage.cs you can gen a reference to your textbox through [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx):

```
TextBox txtName = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txtName");
```

But in a totally unrelated class it's as you suspected, the only way is to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Only as parameter or from code behind class.. Seems no other way